# SwiftUI SF Symbols Image: Dark Mode Image For Light Mode

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, sf-symbols

currently within my app, the images I have in this `ContentView.swift` file **look fine on an iPhone with its display settings set to Dark mode** (1st image) However, when I'm using my simulator that's **set to light mode, it doesn't have good contrast** (2nd image).

Dark mode images (good, what I want both to look like):

[image: dark mode images (good)]

Light mode images (bad, due to low contrast and legibility):

[image: light mode images (bad)]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var sharedVars = SharedVarsBetweenTabs()
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            HomeView().environmentObject(sharedVars)
                .tabItem {
                    Text("Home")
                    Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                }
            AppearanceView().environmentObject(sharedVars)
                .tabItem {
                    Text("Appearance")
                    Image(systemName: "paintbrush.fill")
                  }
            QuotesView().environmentObject(sharedVars)
                .tabItem {
                    Text("Quotes")
                    Image(systemName: "quote.bubble.fill")
                }
        }
        .environmentObject(sharedVars)
        .accentColor(.blue)
    }
        
}
```

Ideally, **I simply want them to both look like the dark mode image, regardless of what the user's phone display setting is**—since the app background is the same. I'd greatly appreciate any help or suggestions.

Comment: In my tests, the light mode does not have a black background like you show, you must have something else going on.
 Note, unrelated but you don't need to use multiple `.environmentObject(sharedVars)`
 the last one is enough.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Thanks for the tip with the `.environmentObject(sharedVars)`.

As for the question, it gives the same look on my installed Quote Droplet app on my iPhone and iPad—just like the screenshot I put from my simulator. I'm not sure what you mean by "something else going on," since this is the only code I have relating to those images.

Comment: You say `However, when I'm using my simulator that's set to light mode, it doesn't have good contrast (2nd image).`
In my tests on a real device and in the simulator, the background is `white` not black, like you show in your post,
`Light mode images (bad, due to low contrast and legibility):...`. So I conclude that maybe you have something else 
in the background.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Yes, to clarify, inside of the views—such as `HomeView()`—I have the view background set to that brown colour. I don't want to edit the background, though, since my question is: how can I make the image look the same in light mode as it does in dark mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force the icon to be independent of the environment very easily. o(>v<)o

Which add with:

```
.onAppear {
  UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.white
}
```

[image: show]

Showing Image Code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  
  var body: some View {
    
    TabView {
      Text("Hi")
        .tabItem {
          Text("Home")
          Image(systemName: "house.fill")
        }
      Text("Hi")
        .tabItem {
          Text("Appearance")
          Image(systemName: "paintbrush.fill")
        }
      Text("Hi")
        .tabItem {
          Text("Quotes")
          Image(systemName: "quote.bubble.fill")
        }
    }
    .accentColor(.blue)
    .onAppear {
      //Backgroud Color
      UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(Color(red: 79/255, green: 65/255, blue: 54/255))
      
      //Icon Color
      UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor(Color(red: 133/255, green: 123/255, blue: 116/255))
    }
    .environment(\.colorScheme, .light)
  }
}

#Preview {
  ContentView()
}
```